# xcode macruby application clang error

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macruby

I am using XCode 5.0 under Mac OS X 10.9. Everytime when i create an macruby application the MacRuby.framework is shown red. After re-adding the path to the framework it isn't red but everytime when i try to build my test application (nothing changed) i became this error:

```
  processPCH /Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/testr-Prefix-buaqdwrexxuknicqaiogcqxxfoyk/testr-Prefix.pch.pch testr/testr-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/Jochen/Documents/MacDev/testr
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang   
   -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack     -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-gc-only -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -fasm-blocks -fno-objc-direct-dispatch -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/testr.build/Debug/testr.build/testr-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/testr.build/Debug/testr.build/testr-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/testr.build/Debug/testr.build/testr-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/testr.build/Debug/testr.build/testr-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/testr.build/Debug/testr.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/testr.build/Debug/testr.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Products/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Library/Frameworks --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/testr-Prefix-buaqdwrexxuknicqaiogcqxxfoyk/testr-Prefix.pch.dia -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/testr-Prefix-buaqdwrexxuknicqaiogcqxxfoyk/testr-Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/Jochen/Documents/MacDev/testr/testr/testr-Prefix.pch -o /Users/Jochen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testr-etdvhjiaivrrrcexrmukckjnqlfk/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/testr-Prefix-buaqdwrexxuknicqaiogcqxxfoyk/testr-Prefix.pch.pch

clang: error: cannot specify both '-fobjc-arc' and '-fobjc-gc-only'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

What is wrong the standard configuration? Anyone an idea?

Comment: MacRuby depends on the garbage collector, which has been deprecated. I don't know enough about Xcode 5 to tell you where to go to turn ARC off, but doing so might help. Last I knew, though, MacRuby still wouldn't work on 10.9.

Comment: But that is very weird. I can't believe that i am the first person who wants to create an Cocoa RubyApplication with MacRuby under 10.9.

Comment: You're not, but there's a lot of work to be done on it. See recent messages in the [macruby-devel mailing list](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macruby-devel/) for details.